Are Romance languages really easier to learn than Germanic ones for English native speakers? If so, why?
Apparently some English speakers find Romance languages easier to learn than Germanic languages.
Considering that English is itself a Germanic language, shouldn't the opposite be true?

Do you have evidence for this claim? Which particular languages (Romanian is supposed to be hard IIRC, Dutch straightforward)? There are various possible reasons (phonology, vocabulary, complexity of case system, availability of learning materials) but it's likely to vary from person to person as well as from language to language.

This is strictly a matter of opinion.

Looking step-by-step at the different aspects of languages may be useful here.

Phonologically, most Romance languages don't pose a significant problem. There are (relatively) few consonants that aren't found in English, and those that are are often reasonably-well approximable with those that are (e.g. English lacks the /ɲ/ of most of Romance, but the contrast between /ɲ/ and /nj/ is so weak that English-speakers approximating it with English /nj/ is unlikely to cause miscommunication).
Likewise, most Romance languages have simple vowel systems that don't pose significant problems to English-speakers (French being a notable exception with its many vowels, including front rounded vowels).
Germanic on the other hand is actually trickier here. Front rounded vowels are common, and whilst there are fewer consonants not found in English, there may be strong contrasts between e.g. /x/ and /h/ that there are not in Romance, making typical English substitutions more likely to cause issues.
So phonologically, Romance is likely to be easier than Germanic because Romance mostly has phonologies that are simpler than that of English, whilst Germanic generally has morphologies that are similarly complex to that of English, but which English has diverged significantly from. This is especially true in the vowel space.

Morphologically, English has lost the vast majority of the native morphology, so a learner is likely to need to need to learn a Romance or Germanic morphology largely from scratch.
Germanic verbs are generally much simpler than in Romance, but the nouns are similarly complex (and in German significantly more complex, because you have case in play as well). Germanic is probably slightly easier on average, but German specifically may be as difficult, or even slightly harder than the average Romance language.

Syntactically English has diverged from the old V2 order quite significantly, now being largely SVO. Whilst this shift has also occurred to varying extents in much of the rest of Germanic, it is much less extensive (and almost non-existent in German itself). Meanwhile, Romance is also largely SVO.
There are some areas where English aligns more with Germanic though, such as adjective order, not being pro-drop, and lacking object clitics for verbs.
In my experience, the nuances of V2 are much harder for English speakers to learn than pro-drop, the different adjective order, or the presence of object clitics in Romance, so Germanic is harder here. This is due to English having diverged significantly from Germanic and ended up in a similar place to where Romance ended up due to Germanic influence on Latin.

Lexically it's important to note that the English lexicon is vast. Whilst it is true that the most common words are overwhelmingly Germanic, the lexicon as a whole is much more mixed and contains a huge number of Romance words.
This means that there is a good chance that a cognate of a word in a Romance language will appear somewhere in the English lexicon, even if it is not the usual word for something. This makes passive comprehension much easier, and aids in acquiring active vocabulary as well.
Additionally, these words mostly entered English in the last millennium, so have had relatively little time to diverge phonologically and semantically from their European correspondents.
Meanwhile, Germanic vocabulary has been in English for significantly longer, and so had much longer to diverge phonologically and semantically, meaning that cognates are less likely to be recognised (e.g. English eye and German Auge "castle" may not be recognised as cognate, or English gift vs German Gift "poison" vs Norwegian gift "married" or "poison" that whilst all recognisably cognate, have evolved to have three very distinct meanings).
Additionally, even where English uses native vocabulary, it oven uses different words that the rest of Germanic, likely due to its relative isolation from the rest of the Germanic words (e.g. English neck where most of the rest of Germanic uses words akin to German Hals where the English cognate halse is almost completely obsolete).
So overall, the lexicon of Germanic languages is probably harder to learn overall because the Germanic words in English have had longer to diverge from their continental cousins or be lost entirely than with the Romance words.

Putting this all together, on average Romance is a little easier phonologically (French les so than the rest of Romance), syntactically (especially compared to German itself), and lexically, whilst Germanic is on average a little easier morphologically.
This is ultimately because English separated from the rest of Germanic a long time before the period of Romance contact, that English has such a large amount of Romance vocabulary, that influence from the rest of Germanic on English was fairly weak, and that Romance was itself structurally influenced by Germanic in ways that aligned it with English.
There is also going to be significant variation between the different languages in question. Dutch or Norwegian are fairly easy phonologically and have also reduced morphology in ways that make it relatively easy for English speakers. German is especially bad morphologically for English speakers due to retaining case. Romanian is difficult on all axes (as it has also suffered large amounts of lexical replacement, in its case by Slavic).
